# Removing grub completely

Tags: grub2, uninstall

I decided to dualboot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a laptop with preinstalled Windows 8. After some work i got both running. After some thoughts I decided to go back to only Windows 8 by restoring from factory settings. When doing this the ubuntu partitions disappeared, and windows loads like it should. But ubuntu is still a boot option in bios. If booting this, i get the grub command-line.

How do I remove the grub loader completely? (I've tried the windows "fixes", fixmbr and fixboot but these yields no results.)

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu  and:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749510%28v=ws.10%29.aspx  And you have to delete the ubuntu folder in the efi partition.

Comment: How do i delete the ubuntu folder in the efi partition? I've followed your links but I have no "Boot manager or similar". I keep deleting the entries in different ways but ubuntu (grub) always finds it way back.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by "trying ubuntu" on a usb stick. Then i mounted the hidden efi partition by using "Disk Utility" which allowed me to delete the ubuntu folder. Then I deleted the boot option on bios.